# Twitter countdown tweet script

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, countdown

I'm trying to run a script that updates my twitter account once a day saying how many days are left to a certain date. I've been using the steps outlined [here](http://www.nostate.com/3982/auto-tweet-a-countdown-to-twitter-from-your-php-website/), but to no success yet. Is the methods used in that tutorial outdated perhaps?

I've uploaded abrahams twitteroauth as outlined, and here is the code I'm using in tweet.php:

```
<?php

require_once('config.php');
require_once('twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php');
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
$today = idate('z', time());
$enddate = idate('z', strtotime('6 June 2013'));
$daysleft = $enddate - $today;

$tweetstr = 'Only ' . $daysleft . ' day';
if ($daysleft > 1) $tweetstr .= 's';
$tweetstr .= " left to this whatever event starts!";

$connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $tweetstr));

?>
```

I've set the twitter app to read, write and direct messages. Am I overlooking anything? I am fairly new to the twitter api.

Here is the error log that occurs when I run the script:

```
[Sat Feb 23 13:18:20 2013] [error] [client 86.40.89.186] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant ACCESS_TOKEN - assumed 'ACCESS_TOKEN' in /var/www/vhosts/darrenmccarra.com/connormccarra.com/lc-tweet-bot/lctweet45i32nd/tweet.php on line 5
[Sat Feb 23 13:18:20 2013] [error] [client 86.40.89.186] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET - assumed 'ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET' in /var/www/vhosts/darrenmccarra.com/connormccarra.com/lc-tweet-bot/lctweet45i32nd/tweet.php on line 5
[Sat Feb 23 13:18:20 2013] [error] [client 86.40.89.186] PHP Warning:  idate() [<a href='function.idate'>function.idate</a>]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'UTC' for 'GMT/0.0/no DST' instead in /var/www/vhosts/darrenmccarra.com/connormccarra.com/lc-tweet-bot/lctweet45i32nd/tweet.php on line 6
[Sat Feb 23 13:18:20 2013] [error] [client 86.40.89.186] PHP Warning:  strtotime() [<a href='function.strtotime'>function.strtotime</a>]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'UTC' for 'GMT/0.0/no DST' instead in /var/www/vhosts/darrenmccarra.com/connormccarra.com/lc-tweet-bot/lctweet45i32nd/tweet.php on line 7
[Sat Feb 23 13:18:20 2013] [error] [client 86.40.89.186] PHP Warning:  idate() [<a href='function.idate'>function.idate</a>]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'UTC' for 'GMT/0.0/no DST' instead in /var/www/vhosts/darrenmccarra.com/connormccarra.com/lc-tweet-bot/lctweet45i32nd/tweet.php on line 7
```

Comment: what is the result you are getting.  Are there any error messages?

Comment: I've added the error log to my original post. Is it a problem with the set server time?

Comment: Actually I got it. The edit with dreamweaver function in cyberduck wasn't actually making changes, whoops! Thanks for your help anyway.